# Overlap two Divs hides contents

Tags: css, hide, html, overlap

We overlap two Divs using "postion:absolute" and z-index.

http://jsfiddle.net/z5GXV/

The text in the green zone (div id="Zone2") is hide by text in the yellow zone (div id="Zone3"). Any help on how to display the text?

Edit1: We can't use nested divs.

Comment: Would you like the text from Zone2 to be shown *through* zone3 or simply move Zone2?

Comment: Do you have the text in the green zone fill the whole width below the yellow zone?

Comment: @Kyle: We will like the text in zone 2 to wrap around text in zone 3.

Comment: @Justus: We don't know how much text will be there but the text should be wrapped around yellow zone.

Comment: @Malik are you satisfied with any of my solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what all the absolute positioning is good for, but you might want to put the yellow zone into the green-zone div, and use a float.

[Solution with a float within the green zone](http://jsfiddle.net/e5R8k/1/)

[Solution with padding](http://jsfiddle.net/4AVkr/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but nested divs are not an option :(. I am wondering is that if we add another zone and add zone 2 and zone 3 at the same level on the new zone. Will this work? Will text be wrapped around zone3(yellow zone)?

Comment: Can't you use nested div's at all? Because you can use this code to generate a placeholder for the yellow div, and put the yellow div with absolute positioning on top of that.

Comment: I am afraid we can't use nested Divs at all. In these divs, "SharePoint Web Part Zones" will be added and "SharePoint Web Part Zones" can't be nested.

Comment: I'm sorry but then I can't think of a css-solution for this problem. With absolute positioning, the elements don't care about other elements around it. They just take the position specified and that's it. You can use padding to make the green zone fill the space below the yellow zone, but there won't be any text there.

Comment: I've added the padding solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can possibly think to do this:

Uses one nested `div` inside the `Zone2` to wrap your text and make it appear as if it's wrapped to `Zone3`.

This is similar to using a `<p>` or `<span>` with `display: block;`.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/AfwWS/).